# Python lxml cssselect nth match

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml

Say i have some html similar to this:

```
<div id="content">
  <span class="green">something</span>
  <span class="blue">something</span>
  <span class="red">something</span>
  <span class="green">something</span>
  <span class="yellow">something</span>
</div>
```

What's the best way to just get the 2nd element using cssselect? 
I can always do `cssselect('span.green')` and then choose the 2nd element from the results, but in a big page with hundreds of elements i guess it's going to be much slower.

Comment: Well, `:nth-match()` is in CSS4, so you won't be able to use it yet.

Comment: Ever heard of [semantic HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML)?

Comment: @BoltClock I was hoping there was some parameter in lxml that will at least tell it to stop looking after finding the element I'm looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not an answer to your question, here is the way I did this:

Use XPath instead of cssselect:

```
>>> from lxml.etree import tostring
>>> from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
>>> x = tostring('<div id="content"><span class="green">something</span><span class="blue">something</span><span class="red">something</span><span class="green">something</span><span class="yellow">something</span></div>')
>>> x.xpath('//span[@class="green"][2]')
[<Element span at b6df71ac>]
>>> x.xpath('//span[@class="green"][2]')[0]
<Element span at b6df71ac>
>>> tostring(x.xpath('//span[@class="green"][2]')[0])
'<span class="green">something</span>'
```

or if you prefer a list of the elements in Python:

```
>>> x.xpath('//span[@class="green"]')
[<Element span at b6df71ac>, <Element span at b6df720c>]
>>> tostring(x.xpath('//span[@class="green"]')[1])
'<span class="green">something</span>'
```